# Can we draw bar chart with two different color/pattern

Tags: highcharts

Can we draw bar chart with more than one color or pattern or line style?

I want to create a bar chart with some part in solid black color and other part in solid green color? Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want some bars to be green and some to be black?  Or do you want a single bar to be half green and half black?  Can you add an image of what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: You can try to use [gradients](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) or use two [stacked series](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked).